# Oozie failed to take stdout for failed actions

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I wrote a oozie workflow with ssh action, if the action is ok then the next action can read its stdout using EL function
`${(wf:actionData('action')['property'])}`.

But in case of failed action, the next action failed to read from previous action stdout.

Is there any alternative for reading stdout from failed action ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide sample workflow.xml you are referring to?

If a node fails then you can use error to="errorHandlingNode"/> and try to access the stdout in error handling node. If not atleast you could get the name of failed node as ${wf:lastErrorNode()}.